# CRS error working with Solaris

Tags: coordinate-system, vector, export, geopandas, fiona

```
result_polys = sol.vector.polygon.georegister_px_df(mask2poly, 
                                               affine_obj=tile_tfm, 
                                               crs= 'epsg:4326')

print(result_polys.crs)
```

epsg:EPSG:4326

```
result_polys.to_file('result_polys.geojson', driver='GeoJSON')
```

> CRSError: Invalid input to create CRS: epsg:EPSG:4326

Answer (score 5):

I'm one of the maintainers for the solaris project. I tried to reproduce your error in my environment but could not.

If you open an issue in [the solaris github repo](https://github.com/cosmiq/solaris) with the full traceback, and your python/solaris/pyproj/fiona versions, then we would be happy to try to figure out what's going on.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/177394)

Comment: @J.Monticolo, can you clarify how I'm supposed to give feedback as the maintainer of the project being asked about, if I don't have enough rep to comment in GIS stackexchange yet, if the answer isn't appropriate?

Comment: I give you an upvote for comments privilege (50) ! But this kind of answer, for me, is more for comments than a proper answer.

Answer (score 4):

According to [Solaris Documentation](https://solaris.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/vector.html#solaris.vector.polygon.georegister_px_df), You have to pass an integer value for `crs`.

> crs (int) – The coordinate reference system for the output GeoDataFrame as an EPSG code integer.

Try to use `4326` instead of `'epsg:4326'`.

```py
result_polys = sol.vector.polygon.georegister_px_df(mask2poly, 
                                                    affine_obj=tile_tfm, 
                                                    crs=4326) ####
```

**But** according to source code, it accepts the following types. You can try them.

1. dict: `crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}`
2. epsg string: `crs = 'epsg:4326'`
3. PROJ4 string: `crs = '+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs'`
4. wkt string: `crs = 'GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984".........]]'`
5. CRS object:

   ```
   from pyproj import CRS        
   crs = CRS("epsg:4326")
   ```

Then, use `crs` :

```
result_polys = sol.vector.polygon.georegister_px_df(mask2poly, 
                                                    affine_obj=tile_tfm, 
                                                    crs=crs) ####
```

Comment: Sahbaz thanks for your inputs. I tried using 4326 instead of 'epsg:4326'. It displays the same error.

Comment: Which version of pyproj do you use? You can learn using `import pyproj; print(pyproj.__version__)`

Comment: It's 2.4.2.post1

Comment: I've updated the answer. I guess the problem is about `fiona`, and I guess, but I'm not so sure, `dict` version solves your problem.

Comment: I tried all these combinations earlier as well. Even I think the problem is with fiona